# How to add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with a Foreach loop Php

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have been trying to add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to the code below, but every time I insert the data in mysql, the data gets added over and over again, while I'd like them to be unique, hence the addition of ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Here is my table:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE sma (
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
short_sma VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
mid_sma VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
long_sma VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
extra_sma VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UC_sma UNIQUE (reg_date,short_sma,mid_sma,long_sma,extra_sma)

)";
```

Here are my attempts with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but none of them works i.e. the data gets added over and over again in my SMA table.

1st attempt:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sma (short_sma, mid_sma, long_sma, extra_sma) VALUES ";

foreach ($uniqe_keys as $key) {    

    $short_sma = array_key_exists($key, $short_smas)?$short_smas[$key]:"";
    $mid_sma = array_key_exists($key, $mid_smas)?$mid_smas[$key]:"";
    $long_sma = array_key_exists($key, $long_smas)?$long_smas[$key]:"";
    $extra_sma = array_key_exists($key, $extra_smas)?$extra_smas[$key]:"";
    // here we build comma separated list of value pairs to insert
    $sql .= "('$short_sma', '$mid_sma', '$long_sma', '$extra_sma'),";
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, ",") ;
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 

  short_sma = '" . $short_sma . "',
  mid_sma = '" . $mid_sma . "',
  long_sma = '" . $long_sma . "',
  extra_sma = '" . $extra_sma . "'

";
```

2nd attempt:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sma (short_sma, mid_sma, long_sma, extra_sma) VALUES ";

    foreach ($uniqe_keys as $key) {    

        $short_sma = array_key_exists($key, $short_smas)?$short_smas[$key]:"";
        $mid_sma = array_key_exists($key, $mid_smas)?$mid_smas[$key]:"";
        $long_sma = array_key_exists($key, $long_smas)?$long_smas[$key]:"";
        $extra_sma = array_key_exists($key, $extra_smas)?$extra_smas[$key]:"";
        // here we build comma separated list of value pairs to insert
        $sql .= "('$short_sma', '$mid_sma', '$long_sma', '$extra_sma'),";
    }

$sql = rtrim($sql, ",") . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

     short_sma = VALUES(short_sma) , mid_sma = VALUES (mid_sma), long_sma = VALUES(long_sma) , extra_sma = VALUES (extra_sma) ";
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you thought about using a unique  constraint?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already using a unique constraint - see table. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint is wrong. Since you want to update all the values except the `reg_date`, only it should be part of the constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT UC_sma UNIQUE (reg_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I add reg_date, I have only one value left in my DB as I can have hundreds of value per second. This constraint layout works in another DB (reg_date,short_sma,mid_sma,long_sma,extra_sma), so it might be something to do with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I got the results I want i.e. no duplicate values. By adding: 
`id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and with `CONSTRAINT UC_sma UNIQUE (price,short_sma,mid_sma,long_sma,extra_sma)` when creating the table and the 2nd attempt code.